# Programmatically exit fullscreen

Tags: javascript

I understand why browsers would disallow websites from programically making the  browser fullscreen. However, users typically expect the 'esc' button to exit from full screen, and browsers simply don't do that.

Is there any way to get the browser to exit from full screen.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this really a problem? If a user wants to be in fullscreen mode, leave their browsing choices alone.  Also, how do you know that the user expects the `esc` button to exit from this mode?

Comment: A user asked me, I have an app which sort of behaves like a youtube video, and through watching videos users have trained their expectations thus.

Answer (score 0):

Well since F11 seems to be the established way to go (at least in FF), how about a key listener that fires an F11 whenever it receives an ESC?